# What should I say salary or salaries?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct?

> They get **a high salary**

or

> They get **high salaries**.

Can I use either?

Comment: Both are fine. We *usually* pluralise ***salaries*** in such contexts (assuming it's not a "singular ***they***" usage), but because each person only gets one salary, it's also okay to use the singular. Consider over a dozen written instances of [***men** live a shorter **life***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22men+live+a+shorter+life%22), for example, where the same principle applies.

Comment: Or, avoid the problem altogether and say, "They are very well paid."

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct only if it refers to a single person of unknown or unspecified gender. In this case the word 'they' is taking the place of 'he or she'. For example:

> "Who is that person who drives such a nice car?" "I don't know but I can tell that they get a high salary."

If the word 'they' is referring to multiple people then the second one is correct.

> "Those people are lawyers. They get high salaries"

The first sentence is often used when referring to multiple people but it's awkward in that context and I wouldn't suggest using it if you want to sound well educated.

> "I'd like to be a doctor. They get a high salary"

Comment: Yes,I really find your answer very helpful.But their is one thing, I need to get it clarified, can I say they got their salaries or should I say they got their salary in this situation.Thanks a lot.

Comment: My third example is an example of what not to say if you want to speak good English. The same thing applies in your second case. It's correct to say, 'They got their salaries.' and incorrect but not unusual to say 'They got their salary.' when talking about multiple people.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Don't forget: you can accept this answer if it was the correct solution.